# cesium: how to check two entities have overlapping area?

Tags: cesiumjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpxSA.png)

I want to check if the two entities have a same area, is Cesium has some apis or functions to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Sandcastle sample](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

```
const {
    BoundingSphere,
    BoundingSphereState,
    Cartesian3,
    Color,
    Viewer
} = window.Cesium;

const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name: "Red polygon on surface",
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
            -115.0,
            44.0,
            -115.0,
            34.0,
            -107.0,
            35.0,
            -102.0,
            34.0,
            -102.0,
            41.0,
        ]),
        material: Color.RED,
    },
});

const greenPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name: "Green extruded polygon",
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
            -108.0,
            42.0,
            -100.0,
            42.0,
            -104.0,
            40.0,
        ]),
        extrudedHeight: 500000.0,
        material: Color.GREEN,
        closeTop: false,
        closeBottom: false,
    },
});

const orangePolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name: "Orange polygon with per-position heights and outline",
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([
            -108.0,
            20.0,
            100000,
            -100.0,
            20.0,
            100000,
            -100.0,
            25.0,
            100000,
            -108.0,
            25.0,
            300000,
        ]),
        extrudedHeight: 0,
        perPositionHeight: true,
        material: Color.ORANGE.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline: true,
        outlineColor: Color.BLACK,
    },
});

function intersect(e1, e2) {
    const b1 = new BoundingSphere();
    const b2 = new BoundingSphere();

    const state1 = viewer._dataSourceDisplay.getBoundingSphere(
        e1,
        false,
        b1
    );

    if(state1 !== BoundingSphereState.DONE ){
        return false;
    }

    const state2 = viewer._dataSourceDisplay.getBoundingSphere(
        e2,
        false,
        b2
    );

    if(state2 !== BoundingSphereState.DONE ){
        return false;
    }

    const dist = Cartesian3.distance(b1.center, b2.center);

    return  dist < (b1.radius + b2.radius);
}

Sandcastle.addToolbarButton("Check intersection", function () {
    console.log(intersect(redPolygon, greenPolygon));
    console.log(intersect(redPolygon, orangePolygon));
});


viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Comment: Can we check if an extruded entity is completely within another extruded entity. Lets say I have a rectangle or polygon entity, can we check if the other polygon or rectangle entity is completely within or not.